# How can i remove "\t" from HashSet List?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void ReadKeysValues()
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"c:\Temp\WritePostedAlready.txt"))
            {
                alreadyPost.UnionWith(File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Temp\WritePostedAlready.txt"));
                for (int i = 0; i < alreadyPost.Count; i++)
                {
                    alreadyPost.Remove("");
                    alreadyPost.Remove("\t");
                }
            }
        }
```

The variable alreadyPost is HashSet
I can remove empty line/s from it doing Remove("");
But i can't remove lines/index\s that start with \t in the beginning.
Doing Remove("\t"); or (@"\t"); is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [RemoveWhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

`alreadyPost.RemoveWhere(p => p.StartsWith("\t"));`

**Update:**

to only remove the `\t` character from each item, but keep the items (see the comments) you can do the following:

```
alreadyPost = new HashSet(
    alreadyPost.Select(p => p.StartsWith("\t") ? p.Substring(1) : p)
);
```

Comment: I do think that tabs should be removed instead of the string \t

Comment: zahorak that move the entire index. If for example index 6 was \t hello everyone . then now the entire index is gone. Instead 9 indexs i have 8. I wanted just to remove the \t. I'm not sure what \t does but i want to remove it only not the entire line.

Comment: You were removing the whole items in your code as well, so I figured that's what you want to do. Otherwise there is no way to update items in a `HashSet` you can just delete them and add modified versions again. - see my update to get a new HashSet where `\t` on the beginning of each item, will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually prevent such items from being added to the set rather than removing them afterwards. However, if you really want to, you can use the following code:

```
foreach (var item in alreadyPost.ToList())
{
    if (item.StartsWith("\t"))
    {
        alreadyPost.Remove(item);
    }
}
```